# What is the next step in the decentralization of education about data analytics?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, internet, academia, git, research-papers

Recently, ArXiv partnered with Github to host links to repos implementing theory contained in papers (possibly eliminating the need for universities and formal education).  What is the next step in making data more available and discoverable...perhaps convincing ArXiv to also request authors provide links to the data sets used by the code in their papers?

Comment: There are three questions here. Which one shall we focus on?

Comment: @anpami please take a look at the edited version.